rspamd error: undefined reference to 'EVP_*'
I am trying to install rspamd, but am encountering the following error:
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable rspamd
librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_get_size'
librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md'
librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding'
librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/rspamd.dir/build.make:196: src/rspamd-3.9.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1802: src/CMakeFiles/rspamd.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 90%] Building C object src/client/CMakeFiles/rspamc.dir/rspamdclient.c.o
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable rspamc
../librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md'
../librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding'
../librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
../librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_CTX_get0_md'
../librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_get_size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/client/CMakeFiles/rspamc.dir/build.make:121: src/client/rspamc-3.9.1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1849: src/client/CMakeFiles/rspamc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2

To build the above, I run:
cmake ../rspamd -DENABLE_HYPERSCAN=ON -DENABLE_LUAJIT=OFF

Initially I suspected the error could be due to my OpenSSL version. I have reinstalled OpenSSL but the error building rspamd remains.
Does anyone have suggestions as to what could be causing the issue ?
I have searched online but cannot find anywhere else describing a solution to this issue.
Tracing back the output from CMake, I find:
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rspamd-server.dir/libserver/hyperscan_tools.cxx.o
/srv/rspamd/src/libserver/hyperscan_tools.cxx:522:7: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
  522 | #endif// defined(HS_MAJOR) && defined(HS_MINOR) && HS_MAJOR >= 5 && HS_MINOR >= 4 \
      |       ^
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rspamd-server.dir/libserver/backtrace.cxx.o
/srv/rspamd/src/libserver/hyperscan_tools.cxx: In function ‘tl::expected<rspamd::util::hs_shared_database, rspamd::util::error> rspamd::util::load_cached_hs_file(const char*, int64_t)’:
/srv/rspamd/src/libserver/hyperscan_tools.cxx:396:14: warning: unused variable ‘log_func’ [-Wunused-variable]
  396 |  const auto *log_func = RSPAMD_LOG_FUNC;
      |              ^~~~~~~~
[ 65%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rspamd-server.dir/libserver/css/css.cxx.o

Tracing back further still, I find:
[ 59%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/rspamd-server.dir/libserver/symcache/symcache_c.cxx.o
In file included from /srv/rspamd/src/libserver/symcache/symcache_runtime.cxx:18:
/srv/rspamd/src/libserver/symcache/symcache_item.hxx: In function ‘constexpr const char* rspamd::symcache::item_type_to_str(rspamd::symcache::symcache_item_type)’:
/srv/rspamd/src/libserver/symcache/symcache_item.hxx:81:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   81 | }
      | ^
[ 60%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/rspamd-server.dir/libserver/task.c.o

I am not sure how to interpret these warnings, or whether they are the cause of the error.

This question is similar to: CMake not able to find OpenSSL library. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The line librspamd-server.so: error: undefined reference to 'EVP_MD_get_size' means that the library librspamd-server.so itself is created incorrectly (a shared library should be able to resolve all symbols it uses). If your output doesn't contain the error at the stage when the library has been created, then the most possible reason is that runtime linkage of the library differs. What ldd shows for librspamd-server.so library? (The library is located somewhere in the build tree.)
